# Debian: Now that buster is stable, how can I "side-grade" away from testing?

Tags: debian, dist-upgrade

I have been on `testing` for a while, and would like a more `stable` system, so I think the best way to accomplish that would be to pin my system to `buster`.

I know downgrades are risky, but I *think* this should be a side-grade, and therefore not risky?

Here's my current setup:

```
------------------------------

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# I've added non-free, to allow installation of nvidia-driver 

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free


------------------------------

$ cat /etc/debian_version
buster/sid
```

Can I just:

1. change all the `testing` to `buster`, or the relevant mirror
2. run `apt update` + `apt dist-upgrade`

So my new `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
```

Comment: I would just re-install, Keeping my `/home`. Then run my configuration scripts (to get 90% of the system back. They are not perfect.)

Comment: Since it's risky I won't risk an answer heh. You have to change apt_preferences(5) to get buster to priority 1001 or more, allowing downgrades. Then you'll have to resolve as you can all package clashes the dependency resolver doesn't manage to find a solution for. Then you should carefully note all downgraded packages. Once done, before any reboot, you should apt --reinstall install all the list that was changed. That's to avoid files getting lost due to package logic not always applicable with downgrades. After this you can only wish you didn't break your system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right time to “side-grade” from testing to the latest stable release of Debian is when testing becomes stable, or shortly thereafter. The main indicator that such a change is no longer possible is when the next version of [glibc](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/glibc) migrates to testing — and that happened [in mid-September](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1064710/glibc-229-1-migrated-to-testing/).

In any case, you’re in unsupported downgrade territory; it only gets worse after the glibc bump because you’re then more likely to have to downgrade large numbers of packages in one go.

Changing your repository configuration as you suggest won’t actually cause any change when you next run `apt upgrade` (or even `apt full-upgrade`), because APT doesn’t downgrade packages by default. To switch from testing to stable, you’d also have to (temporarily) configure your [pin priorities](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html) so that Buster packages have a priority greater than 1000:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=buster
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Then “upgrade”, taking careful note of all the downgrades, and as [A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) mentions, re-installing affected packages to make sure all their files are present.

I would recommend *not* doing this. You’d be better off re-installing stable, or staying on testing until the next stable release (probably sometime in 2021).

Comment: My `/etc/debian_version` was `buster/sid`, I presume because I didn't run upgrades since Buster became stable in September. So before you answered I actually went through with these changes, and it seems to work, and now the vesion is just `buster` (no `/sid`). Might this have worked, or do you expect I might have some lurking conflict?

Comment: Ah, good, if your version was still `buster/sid` that does indeed mean you hadn’t upgraded since Buster became stable (or rather, since `base-files` changed to `bullseye/sid`, in July). So your system should be fine!